# Create SEO URL for that link?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Guys i have that link:

```
http://kika-makeup.dev.extensa.bg/index.php?route=information/information
```

how to become to that link:

```
http://kika-makeup.dev.extensa.bg/information
```

I tried with this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/information/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?route=information/information
```

Comment: Shouldn't that shortened path also be `information/information` anyway?

Comment: just "information"

Answer (score 0):

Here's why your regex won't match:

```
RewriteRule ^/information/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?route=information/information
             ↑               ↑
   leading slash          There's no numbers in your
  does not match          shortened input path.
    in .htaccess          »http://example/information«
```

And since you gave no further details, this is just a sample about how to internally rewrite your one input path:

```
RewriteRule ^(information)$ index.php?route=information/$1
```

For more examples on how to match things, see [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried with this code:

RewriteBase /kika_makeup/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=(information/information)$
RewriteRule ^(information)$ /index.php?route=information/$1

Comment: This looks like you're attempting something else entirely. Not answerable without context and RewriteLog.